# sublime text 3 Untitled file temp location

Tags: sublimetext3

I was using build 3126 of sublime text 3 and there were 4 untitled files. Whenever I run sublime text 3, those files were also opened in 4 tabs.

I was lasted updated to build 3143. By mistake I was not saved those opened files. And after update complete, sublime text 3 opened automatically. But those 4 files are vanished.

Is there anyway to get those file, if available in any temp location?

I am using windows 10.

Comment: The state of files being open or not is a part of the session file. Not sure if it's backed up, but I don't think it should have just been thrown away by the update unless you manually erased it during your update process.

Comment: I was just closed previously opened window when update installation started. After installing update done, that opens new window for updated version. But all previous not saved (untittled) tabs are not there this time.